# Comparing two numbers using if/else statements

Tags: java

I'm stumped trying to figure out how to compare two numbers to determine which one is larger and which one is smaller using if/else statements.

As it stands, whenever I compile my code I get this error:

> method setNums in class NumberCompare cannot be given to applied types; required: no arguments, found:int,int; reason:actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I am pretty sure that my class is not done well. So here is what I currently have.

`NumberCompare` class:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class NumberCompare
{
    private int numberA, numberB;
    public NumberCompare(int a, int b)
    {
        numberA=a;
        numberB=b;
    }
    public void setNums ()
    {
        numberA = 45;
        numberB = 45;
    }
    public int getLargest ()
    {
        if(numberA > numberB)
            System.out.println(+numberA+" is greater than " +numberB);
        return numberA;
    }
    public int getSmallest ()
    {
        if(numberA < numberB)
            System.out.println(+numberB+" is less than " +numberA);
        return numberB;
    }
}
```

And the runner class:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class NumberCompareRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        NumberCompare test = new NumberCompare(5,6);
        out.println(test);
        out.println("largest == " + test.getLargest());
        out.println("smallest == " + test.getSmallest()+"\n\n");
        test.setNums(45,45);
        out.println(test);
        out.println("largest == " + test.getLargest());
        out.println("smallest == " + test.getSmallest()+"\n\n");
        test.setNums(-25,10324);
        out.println(test);
        out.println("largest == " + test.getLargest());
        out.println("smallest == " + test.getSmallest()+"\n\n");
    }
}
```

So in short my issue is that I can't get two numbers to be compared against each other. Thanks for any and all help. I also deeply apologize for my immature previous posting of this issue.

Comment: Put an effort into telling us what the problem is and we'll try and help.

Comment: Whaaaaaaaaaaat is the problem or error you have?

Answer (score 2):

Your method to set the numbers as defined:

```
public void setNums ()
{
    numberA = 45;
    numberB = 45;
}
```

Does not allow the user to specify new ones.

Change the signature to allow new numbers to be set from the user:

```
public void setNums (int a, int b)
{
    numberA = a;
    numberB = b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cηαnge your NumberCompare class as follows:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class NumberCompare
{
    // Rest of the code here
    public void setNums (int a, int b){
        numberA = a;
        numberB = b;
    }
    public int getLargest (){
        if(numberA > numberB){
            System.out.println(+numberA+" is greater than " +numberB);
            return numberA;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(+nuberB+" is greater than " +numberA);
            return numberA;
        }
    }
    public int getSmallest ()
    {
        if(numberA < numberB){
            System.out.println(+numberA+" is less than " +numberB);
            return numberA;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(+numberB+" is less than " +numberA);
            return numberB;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem you had was due to the setNums method, not accepting the proper arguments. Also I couldn't help but notice a wrong implementation on the rest of the methods, so I propose a solution for those, too.
That is because in your original code you only checked if A was smaller or larger than B and you returned A regardless as it was not in a code block for the if statement. Adding an else statement to each if and handling the case that B is your result is reasonably easy.

Answer (score 0):

Remove setnums method and create new object each time:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class NumberCompare
{
    private int numberA, numberB;
    public NumberCompare(int a, int b)
    {
        numberA=a;
        numberB=b;
    }
    public int getLargest ()
    {
        if(numberA > numberB)
            System.out.println(+numberA+" is greater than " +numberB);
        return numberA;
    }
    public int getSmallest ()
    {
        if(numberA < numberB)
            System.out.println(+numberB+" is less than " +numberA);
        return numberB;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class NumberCompareRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        NumberCompare test = new NumberCompare(5,6);
        out.println(test);
        out.println("largest == " + test.getLargest());
        out.println("smallest == " + test.getSmallest()+"\n\n");
        test = new NumberCompare(45,45);
        out.println(test);
        out.println("largest == " + test.getLargest());
        out.println("smallest == " + test.getSmallest()+"\n\n");
        test = new NumberCompare(-25,10324);
        out.println(test);
        out.println("largest == " + test.getLargest());
        out.println("smallest == " + test.getSmallest()+"\n\n");
    }
}
```